# complex variable creation in R

Tags: r, variables

I would like to create a complex variable in R. Imagine I have the following data:

```
Year id  A  B  C
1    1   2  1  2 
2    1   2  1  3
3    1   2  1  3
1    2   3  2  3
2    2   3  2  5
3    2   3  2  5
```

I want to create variable C which equals variable A when the year is 1and then is A + B for the following years (2 and 3). I am trying the following function:

```
df$C <- ifelse(df$Year == 1, df$A, ifelse(df$Year != 1), df$A+df$B)
```

But I get an error stating that `>=` is not meaningful for factors. Any idea on how to create variable C?

Comment: So very close.  Try `df$C <- ifelse(df$Year == 1, df$A, df$A+df$B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df$C <- ifelse(df$Year == 1, df$A, df$A+df$B)
```

You dont need to be explicit about df$Year != 1, as df$A+df$B is chosen when df$Year != 1

Comment: glad it solved the issue, thank me by accepting it :)